# How to include a header privately in C

Tags: c, header, include

How to include a header file in c privately so that files that include the file that includes the header wont include the header.

for example:

`main.c`

```c
#include "main.h"
```

`main.h`

```c
#include "test.h"
// I want main.c not to include test.h
```

I would like to know how to do that

Comment: You can use conditional compilation

Comment: define a macro only in main.c (before including main.h) and test for that

Comment: I dont want to generate C code because it does not help me, but thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `#define`:

in main.c

```
// the define MUST be before main.h inclusion
#define IN_MAIN_C
#include "main.h"
```

in main.h

```
#ifndef IN_MAIN_C
#include "test.h"
#endif
```